# Permutations using same letters

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

I am current working on a project where I need to generate all possible permutations from a given set of characters. I am currently using this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllPermutations(this IEnumerable<char> s)
{
    return s.SelectMany(x =>
    {
        var index = Array.IndexOf(s.ToArray(), x);
        return s.Where((y, i) => i != index).AllPermutations().Select(y => new string(new[] { x }.Concat(y).ToArray())).Union(new[] { new string(new[] { x }) });
    }).Distinct();
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474324/799586) answer.

The problem I have is that it won't generate permuations that use the same letter more than once.

For example if I used `abcde` as the input I need it to generate combinations like `aaaaa` and `dcc` etc.

I'm not experienced enough with LINQ to understand where the code is stopping duplicate letters. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this in LINQ?

Comment: I didn't write this, so was just looking for code that did the job really.

Comment: 'aaaaa' is not a permutation of 'abcde'.  If your project requires permutations don't include 'aaaaa', if you include 'aaaaa' don't call it a permutation (or a combination for that matter).  You'll just confuse everyone reading your question, including yourself.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is variation with repetitions.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, I am very confused :) I'm not sure what terminology to use for what I need...

Comment: Perhaps you want all the 5 letter words from the alphabet 'abcde' ?

Comment: I also need any shorter versions, from 1 character to the string length, using all the input letters in any order.

Comment: so it's just a base 5 number system, then just count from 'a' to 'eeeee'

Comment: @PeskyGnat Yeah, I guess, but how do I do that then?

Comment: @BaliC: Just to be clear, for a given string on length n, all possible variations of length 1 to n including repeated characters? Is order important? In other words do you want both "ab" and "ba"?

Comment: @MattBurland Yeah thats right. If I gave "abc" I would want a, aa, aaa, ab, ba, etc - all combos, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *might* work, but I'm sure it could be done more efficiently (taking the counting prompt from PeskyGnat):

```
    static IEnumerable<string> GetVariations(string s)
    {
        int[] indexes = new int[s.Length];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (IncrementIndexes(indexes, s.Length))
        {
            sb.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (indexes[i] != 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(s[indexes[i]-1]);
                }
            }
            yield return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    static bool IncrementIndexes(int[] indexes, int limit)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
        {
            indexes[i]++;
            if (indexes[i] > limit)
            {
                indexes[i] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Edit: Changed to use yield return as per Rawlings suggestion. Much better memory usage if you don't need to keep all the results and you can start using the results before they've all been generated.

Comment: That is absouletly brilliant! I can't thank you enough. +1 and accept, thanks!

Comment: Whether or not this could be done more efficiently, I'm sure it could be done a lot less efficiently. E.g. my answer :D

Comment: @Rawling: Actually one thing mine doesn't do that your does is deal with duplicates. For example, if the string is "cca", mine will spit out "caa" twice, once for each "c" which it sees as different. Yours doesn't do that.

Comment: I couldn't figure out which one to upvote, they both ran out of memory at some point, i.e. with an input string of "abcdefghijk", but work well enough for small cases

Comment: @Pesky There is a way of doing this that uses O(1) space (as long as you don't _keep_ all of the strings you get out) but I'm not capable of remembering it right now.

Comment: @PeskyGnat: No doubt. I only tried it up to about 8 characters which took a few seconds to run. It's a problem that blows up really quickly.

Comment: @Matt Oh, mine doesn't _intentionally_ deal with duplicates. Yours is in fact the O(1)-space solution I was thinking of, if you just switch to using `yield return` instead of a `List`. Edit: in fact the duplicates thing is trivial, just check the length of the input string, then strip it of duplicate characters before using it as your input...

Comment: Yes, the yield would make this handle larger values without any memory overhead, and adhere more closely to the original interface of returning an Enumerable

Comment: @Rawling: Good suggestion on the yield return. I always forget about that feature.

Answer (score 3):

I'm amazed this works. It basically goes "make a list of strings from the characters. Then to each string taken from the list, add each character again, and add the resulting strings to the list. Repeat until you've got the right length."

```
public static IEnumerable<string> BuildStrings(this IEnumerable<char> alphabet)
{
    var strings = alphabet.Select(c => c.ToString());
    for (int i = 1; i < alphabet.Count(); i++)
    {
        strings = strings.Union(strings.SelectMany(s => alphabet.Select(c => s + c.ToString())));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: Aha, it only works because I'm doing `Union` rather than `Concat`, otherwise I'd have many, many duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

A funny one using only recursive lambdas via a fixpoint operator (thx @Rawling for the *SelectMany*)

```
// Fix point operator   
public static Func<T, TResult> Fix<T, TResult>(Func<Func<T, TResult>, Func<T, TResult>> f)
    {
        return t => f(Fix<T, TResult>(f))(t);
    }
```

And then

```
var chars = new[] {'a','b','c','d','e'}.Select(c=>c.ToString()) ;

var result = Fix<int,IEnumerable<string>>(
    f => 
      x => 
       x == 1
         ? chars
         : chars.Union(f(x - 1).SelectMany(s => chars.Select(c => s + c))))(chars.Count());
```